# How does the thread state of Java map to linux? If the state of Java is runnable, what is on Linux

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

How does the thread state of Java map to linux? If the state of Java is runnable, what is on Linux?

Jstack shows that the thread state of Java is TIMED_WAITING, but the PS command shows that the thread state of Linux is R, why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java documentation clearly says

> A thread can be in only one state at a given point in time. These states are virtual machine states which do not reflect any operating system thread states.

There is no true mapping. You can read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html)

Comment: On linux, every java thread corresponds to a Linux lwp. Shouldn't thread state be relevant? The docs you provide only describe the thread state of java, not Linux

Comment: Java works on jvm not linux, jvm works on linux so only jvm needs to reflect ops thread state. Docs is clearly saying this.